# Check if object is a custom class?

Tags: php

I have a base class that defines a bunch of db interaction like insert, delete or fetch. This class is inherited by various other classes, some of which have custom classes as variable types.

The database doesn't support types other than numerals or strings though so I have to serialize objects before insertion and deserialize after. I would like to automate this and add the functionality to my base class.

Is there a way to tell if a variable is a user defined type? (and not a specific type but any)

Comment: add your code to your question

Comment: What do you mean by `a variable is a user defined type`? Can you provide example?

Comment: @Justinas its when you write "class user_defined_type_name {}"

Comment: For me it's just another class declaration. Class is not custom variable

Comment: @justinas you can't seriously propose that there isn't an epic difference between user classes and types such as a string or an integer

Comment: `new MySuperCustomClass` and `new StdClass` both are `object` type. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/de65450edd5c913d596d3e71aa270cd449acab25

Comment: @justinas thats an awesome non-solution, I'm looking for ways to tell them apart, not how they are similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this: [instance of](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php)

```
if ($variable instanceof MyCustomClass){
     //do something    
}
```